# Visual Studio 2012 Could not prepare files for refactoring

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, dotnetnuke

When I try to do a simple refactoring (rename a function parameter) I receive the following message.

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Could not prepare '<path to my project>\DesktopModules\Admin\ModuleCreator\Templates\C#\Class File\template.cs' for refactoring.
---------------------------
ОК   
---------------------------
```

I was able to do such refactorings few days ago. I do not know what happened.

I have the following software installed. I did not install anything since the refactoring worked last time.

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012
Version 11.0.61030.00 Update 4
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.50938

Installed Version: Ultimate

Architecture and Modeling Tools   04940-004-0038003-02455
LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2012   04940-004-0038003-02455
Office Developer Tools   04940-004-0038003-02455
Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2012   04940-004-0038003-02455
Visual Basic 2012   04940-004-0038003-02455
Visual C# 2012   04940-004-0038003-02455
Visual C++ 2012   04940-004-0038003-02455
Visual F# 2012   04940-004-0038003-02455
Visual Studio 2012 Code Analysis Spell Checker   04940-004-0038003-02455
Visual Studio 2012 SharePoint Developer Tools   04940-004-0038003-02455
ASP.NET and Web Tools   2012.3.41009
NuGet Package Manager   2.6.40627.9000
PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.0
SQL Server Data Tools   11.1.20627.00
VisualSVN   4.0.7
```

I have a solution with 4 projects. One of them is a DNN Web Site, and the other 3 are DLLs used by the DNN project.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `~/DesktopModules/Admin/ModuleCreator` folder (unless you use it)

See https://dnnmodulecreator.codeplex.com/ for what it does, and  decide for yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I cannot check it, because I installed Resharper and do refactoring with Resharper, not with native VS commands. Resharper does them fine.

Comment: I just closed and re-opened VS, and it worked for me.